# Edge moves entire HTML element off left of screen when form radiobutton clicked?

Tags: css, html, forms, radio-button, microsoft-edge

As you can see from the below images, Edge (and only Edge) has decided to shift my entire HTML element an unknown number of pixels to the left, off the screen. Why? I'm using a custom radiobutton design but the underlying HTML is the same. Has anyone seen this before?

[image: Before breaking]

[image: After breaking]

(Side note: If it helps, I can arrange a live version of the page for you guys to have a crack at - should anyone request it)

Comment: can you please share the url or the code.

Comment: 10(ish) more minutes and I'll have a live URL.

Comment: Can't help without the code. Waiting for the live URL.

Comment: Can't add the link to the edit - so here it is:
http://ofcourse-debugging.azurewebsites.net/

. Sorry for the wait!

Answer (score 0):

The shift is caused by the `.radio input[type='radio']` element being absolute positioned.

You can fix this multiple different ways.

1: Add `position: relative;` to your `.radio` css selector.

2: Remove the `position: absolute;` from `.radio input[type='radio']` and add `display: none;` in it's place.

3: Remove the `position: absolute;` from `.radio input[type='radio']` and add `height: 0; width: 0;` in it's place.